# custom input fields over google maps possible?

Tags: css, maps

i use google maps on a website.
is it possible to position custom inputfields on the map?
the custom fields are not a port of googles api.
if it is possible, does google allow this?

First i have just to know if it is possible. i asked our developers. But no of them know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like the below result!!!!!

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d15781.912376898357!2d76.87786109999999!3d8.549939649999999!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1498051352217" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <div class="absolute">
    <form method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="test" value="Input box here" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```